# How to implement POST method in AsyncTask to write JSON data through API in android studio?

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

I want to POST JSON data having nested objects in it with the help of Asynctask in android studio, but I don't have good knowledge of API implementation in android studio. I am all new in android studio. I have successfully POST this data from POSTMAN, but I am not able to implement the code for it, also I don't have any tutorials for Asynctask. Please help me to implement code for this.

This is my Json data having nested Objects in it:
[image: Img]

Comment: Use retrofit, which can asynchronously do these tasks easily for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need Async, [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) does it in the background for you. Put your JSONObject in the method instead of 'new JSONObject'. And YourURL - i.e '/api/route/'.

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

JsonObjectRequest request_json = new JsonObjectRequest(YourURL, new JSONObject(params)),
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        //Do what you want on response 
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            //If there's an error...
        }
    });

    //Add process to queue to get JSON in background thread
    queue.add(request_json);
```

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays a better/simpler approach would be to use a libary like [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) to do all the magic for you.

You can simply send a Java instance model to an API endpoint. Retrofit takes care of converting it to json when using the GsonConverterFactory class and sends the json to the endpoint you provided with the given HTTP method.

Answer (score 0):

Best and Simple Library for Implementation for API services by third party library made by Square, Retrofit a Easy HTTP Client.

Why Retrofit? because, Retrofit automatically creates the background thread ,Parse the Json using GSON converter and get a call success and Failure call back directly on main thread. Without writing too much boiler plate code of AsyncTask and Parsing JSON and getting the result on main thread.

Make Retrofit Client.

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("https://api.github.com/")
    .build();

RetrofitInterface service = retrofit.create(RetrofitInterface.class);
```

Make Method in RetrofitInterface.

```
@POST("users/new")
Call<User> yourMethod(@Body UserType user);
```

Now Call your method and It will make your success and Failure Callback method

```
Call<List<Repo>> repos = service.yourMethod("octocat");
```

And then Call enque method to automatic create background thread.

```
repos.enqueue(new Callback<List<Repo>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Repo>> call, Response<List<Repo>> response) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<MainResponse> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
```